# Unique Facebook Comments with Viddler Playlist Videos

Tags: facebook, video, comments

Is it possible to change the Facebook Comments box on a page to a new one when a user changes a video within our Viddler playlists?

The playlist changes on the same page with no refresh, so if I just insert one FB comment box it will stay the same no matter what video is called up.

I know it would be possible with javascript...

Here is the script which was created here to do the playlist change:

```
$(".playlist-link").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var playlist = $(this).attr("href");

var url = 'http://www.viddler.com/tools/vidget.js' +
              '?widget_type=js_list' +
              '&widget_width=940' +
              '&source=playlist' +
              '&user=Fanaticgroup' +
              '&playlist='+ playlist +
              '&style=grid'+
              '&show_player=true'+
              '&player_type=simple'+
              '&max=12'+
              '&videos_per_row=6'+
              '&v=2.0'+
              '&id=7476737550';

$.getScript(url, function(data, textStatus){

});
});
```

Now this does the job perfectly and leaves it open for me to call other functions after the playlist is chosen, like auto start the first video ect.

Is there a way of calling a new FB comment box onto the page after the playlist is changed, and upon each new video?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Facebook Documentation, you can insert the comment social plugin using html like so:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://example.com" data-num-posts="2" data-width="500"></div>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=132892600147693";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

It should be simple enough, at that point to do something similar to this:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.yourdomain.com/some/unique/path/identifying/your/playlist" data-num-posts="5" data-width="500"></div>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=YOUR_APP_ID";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

var commentContainerTemplate = $('.fb-comments').clone();
function loadNewPlaylistComments(playlist_id)
{
    var currentComments = $('.fb-comments'),
    newComments = commentContainerTemplate.clone()
            .data('href', "http://www.yourdomain.com/some/unique/path/identifying/your/playlist/" + playlist_id)
            .before(currentComments);

    currentComments.remove();

    FB.XFBML.parse( newComments.get() );
}
</script>
```

Then, every time you call `loadNewPlaylistComments()` the old comments will be removed, a new comment container will be added to the page, and the FB XFBML parser will be executed.  That should load the comments for the new playlist.  It may take a few seconds for the new comments to load, so I suggest you build in some kind of loading indicator for the user, once you get everything figured out.

Comment: Yeah that would do it. Well I will have to keep you in the loop on this one once I get round to installing the comments. Thank you kindly though!